# VBA, loop column and copy cell format if value match in other range on same sheet

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have a table that has 4 columns -- the category of the event, the start date, the end date, and if it has been confirmed. The type of event is color coordinated, and formatted using conditional formatting.

[here is the table that I reffering to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Um7uR.png)

In the same sheet we also have miniature calendars that look like this

[calendars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZmOs.png)

I want to be able to take the formatting that was applied to the category column, and then using the start date and end date in the table, populate the corresponding dates in the miniature calendars with the formatting from the category column

I have tried writing some VBA scripts, but am very new to VBA. Is something like this possible or is it a big ask for something that would be pretty simple to do by hand?

Comment: So you'd want July 3, 4, and 5 highlighted in Green? Is that set via conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes, the green comes from the category column in the table which is set by conditional formatting.

Comment: it would be easier if the dates in the calendars are actual dates values just formatted as "d", you are also using merge cells it is tricky to iterate ranges with merge cells